# I need to calculate amount depends of company

Tags: php, mysql, postgresql, symfony

I need to calculate the sum of the amount with distinct.

Bellow my data model

**cars**

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | BMW |

**users**

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | John |
| 2 | Alice |
| 3 | Doe |

**car_users**

| car_id | user_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 3 |

**companies**

| id | amount |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1000 |
| 2 | 1000 |

**user_companies**

| user_id | company_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 2 |

My question is, I need to get a sum of the amount of the companies table with distinct like

```
SELECT c.id, c.name, sum(company.amount) amount
FROM cars c
LEFT JOIN car_users cu ON c.id = cu.car_id
LEFT JOIN users u ON u.id = cu.user_id
LEFT JOIN user_companies uc ON u.id = uc.user_id
LEFT JOIN companies comp ON comp.id = uc.company_id
```

So I need to get `2000` for the amount because users 1 & 1 have the same company

This actually a request returning `3000` because the calcul is done on the 3 users of user_compnaies table

PS: if someone has the request in DQL (Symfony) it's makes me happy

Thank you for the help.

Comment: Why are you joining at all over all of your tables, if you're just interested in the `SUM` of the amount of the companies?

Comment: Cause I need to display amount in `SELECt c.id, c.name, sum(company.amount) FROM cars c`

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with the following query:

```sql
SELECT SUM(a.amount), id, name
FROM (
SELECT DISTINCT uc.company_id, c.id, c.name, comp.amount
FROM cars c
LEFT JOIN car_users cu ON c.id = cu.car_id
LEFT JOIN users u ON u.id = cu.user_id
LEFT JOIN user_companies uc ON u.id = uc.user_id
LEFT JOIN companies comp ON comp.id = uc.company_id
) AS a
GROUP BY a.id, a.name
```

In the inner query, you will use your `DISTINCT` which will filter out the duplicate company `1`. Then you can sum over this result.

Actually I'm not sure, if this is possible in doctrine DQL. But you can use the inline SQL there and that should work.